# wxPython: How to synchronize a grid with a matplotlib canvas

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to build a multypane wxAUI application with a multipane structure.

I have two class of objects that are controlled by an AuiManager (_mgr) that are:
1) wx.Grid.CSheet objects inserted into an AuiNotebook inside a pane 
2) Matplotlib.figure objects also incapsulated into an other AuiNotebook inside the same AuiManager.

Here are the two classes defining the corresponding objects.

```
class MySheet(sheet.CSheet):
""" A Copy&Paste enabled grid class"""

def __init__(self, parent,NRows,NCols):
    sheet.CSheet.__init__(self, parent)
    wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self, self.OnKey)

    self.SetLabelBackgroundColour('#DBD4D4')
    self.SetNumberRows(NRows)
    self.SetNumberCols(NCols)
          self.NRows = NRows
          self.NCols = NCols

def selection(self):
    MORE CODE HERE
def OnKey(self, event):
    MORE CODE HERE
def copy(self):
    MORE CODE HERE
def paste(self):
    MORE CODE HERE
def delete(self):
    MORE CODE HERE

class Plot(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, dpi = None, **kwargs):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, **kwargs)
    self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=dpi, figsize=(2,2))
    self.canvas = Canvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    self.toolbar = Toolbar(self.canvas)
    self.toolbar.Realize()

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0 , wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

class PlotNotebook(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, id = -1):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id)
    self.nb = wx.aui.AuiNotebook(self)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

def add(self,name="plot"):
   page = Plot(self.nb)
   self.nb.AddPage(page,name)
   return page.figure
```

AS default I have set two figures and two grid with two columns each correponding to X and Y data respectively. I would like to synchronize the X,Y data in a grid with the corresponding figure so that when these are changed also the figure is updated.

At creation time I'm able to fill the grids and figures with my data content, but I'm not able to updated the figure content after a change event such as when new data are pasted into the grid. I've tryed using after the update figure.canvas.draw() and _mgr.Update() but they seems not to work despite I don't get any error.